# Display bug causes number of badges to be shown incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, badges

There is a display bug which causes the number of badges to be shown incorrectly.
Here is an example from [Are there any disadvantages of TeX being Turing complete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58042/are-there-any-disadvantages-of-tex-being-turing-complete) where the number of bronze badges is displayed as "32" not "322":

[image]

I doubt that this is intended behavior (does not happen on SO with Jon Skeet for example)

Here's another bad example (by doncherry):

[image]

Comment: (For clarification for people who don't immediately see the bug) Martin Scharrer has 322 bronze badges. I get the bug as well (Firefox 8.0 on Linux Mint).

Comment: For this specific example, I don't get the bug with FF12.0 on Win7-64, but I remember seeing similar things. @soandos: Which browser on which OS are you using?

Comment: Confirmed with Opera 11.64 and Opera 12 (beta) on Windows 7.

Comment: Also I have the normal behavior (322 fully printed) with Win7-64, FF 12 (same as @doncherry).

Comment: LOL `:D` I'd call it the 'too-many-badges-to-display' bug! Clearly the badges are 'out-of-the-box'. Even the end of the '2' in '32' is slightly clipped.

Comment: @doncherry, Chrome 19

Comment: This reminds me on the impending issue I mentioned at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=4490605#4490605, also see the second image a few messages down. ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can no longer be reproduced. Flair now wraps rather than being hidden.

Answer (score 15):

The line with the bronze badges is getting clipped if it is too long. The HTML code of the website contains the full number "322" which is clipped here to "32". If you look closely to the displayed "2" you see that it gets a little clipped as well.

The CSS settings used to style each site is different from SX site to SX site, so e.g. SO seems to not be effected. Therefore the responsible CSS setting should be found and changed in order to fix this.

---

I now found the responsible CSS setting. There is a `overflow: hidden` as part of the `user-details`:

```
.user-info .user-details {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 145px;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. I will mark it as correct when the bug is fixed

Comment: @soandos: I notified one of the SX designers about it now. It might be fixed soon.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Perhaps they'll look at some of the other [design problems](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+design+-status-completed+-status-bydesign?sort=votes&pagesize=50) as well ...

Comment: Another idea: shorten `322` to `3h`. Nobody seems to count badges by one when there're hundereds. (Maybe apply this rule only when both bronze and silver are at least 100?)

Comment: The bug is still active... @soandos

Answer (score 5):

While I totally acknowledge that truncating the user info card is not optimal, we have to adapt it to many different designs.

It is a common assumption in our design that this card has a fixed width: hence, the `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Maybe hide the bronze badges if they don't fit in? Because the current version seems to be the worst option :-/

Comment: One could even hide _all_ badges at least for editors of questions/answers. They're not really important information. In fact I never have cared for the number of badges anyone has. To me it is quite useless information. If I _want_ to know about the badges someone has I go to their user profile anyway

Comment: Sorry, but I find this very far from being an answer. It's just a comment saying: “We don't have time for fixing this  obvious bug”. You don't want to fix it? Fine, but, please, don't say “I acknowledge it's not optimal”, which is simply ridiculous.

Comment: @egreg I don't even understand this answer. If that is so, why doesn't the bug manifest on all sites - if it is a problem caused by a 'one-size-fits-all' measure?