# What eats my name?! And how to fight it?

Tags: support, flair

Recently I have observed that my name (Przemysław Scherwentke) has in some automatic signatures the last "e" eaten. See, for example, [Tkz-berge graphs, equal arrows with unequal subfigures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263086)

[image]

This didn't happen, say, half a year ago. What causes this unexpected behaviour and how can I obtain my full name back?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can no longer be reproduced. Flair names now wrap rather than being hidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a limited amount of real estate at the bottom of a post since it's width is fixed. The site might be responsive to resizing horizontally, but the "information width" does not change. To this end, the *flair* box width is also fixed. A similar problem is experienced when you have a large number of badges (see the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [Display bug causes number of badges to be shown incorrectly](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2516/5764)).

Understandably Stack Exchange enforces some limit in terms of what can be displayed, but allows users the freedom to enter whatever they want for a name in their user/network profile. As such, some names are visually truncated, while others are not. Here's [another example on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260589/168244):

[image]

Comment: I understand that there is a limit. However I am sure that some time ago one additional character in my name appeared. What have happened? A world crisis?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: You might remember that there was an entire [design change](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6061/5764) on all the graduated sites. I'm thinking the updated CSSs may have something to do with this. It's been around for a couple of months (since April 2015).

Comment: Yes, I remember. That also spoiled a well working version. So there is no chance to retrieve the previous functionality? I am afraid what will be spoiled in future... Tex.sx will excise my kidney during my sleep? >:-O

Comment: It was also fonts that got changed, a lot of spacing was affected by this.